# How to ensure when content pasted in forms, the forms values updates immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a form that works fine except **when I paste content directly in my form, the input is failed to be registered by my program**.

*However, when I enter the value manually, it works ok.*

Concretely when I paste content in form my validation mechanism seems to be blind toward the freshly pasted value and I can't figure out why.

here my form.js :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import validator from "validator";

import style from "./Form.css";

class Signup extends Component {
  state = {
    email: {
      value: "",
      validation: false
    },
    password: {
      value: "",
      validation: false
    },
    validateForm: false,
    nameSubmit: "offSubmit"
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.validateForm) {
      return alert("please fill the form");
    }
    // call http quest...

    // reset form to false
    this.setState({ nameSubmit: "offSubmit" });
    this.setState({ validateForm: false });
    return alert("submit success =)");
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let scope = this;

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: Object.assign({}, this.state[e.target.name], {
        value: e.target.value
      })
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("password", scope.state.password.value);
    }, 1000);

    if (e.target.name === "email") {
      // reducerUpdateMail
    }

    if (e.target.name === "password") {
      //   reducerUpdatePassword
    }

    this.checkForm(e);
  };

  checkForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("checkform join");
    let scope = this;
    if (e.target.name === "email") {
      let email = e.target.value.trim();
      if (
        typeof email === "string" &&
        email.length >= 1 &&
        validator.isEmail(email)
      ) {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: Object.assign({}, this.state[e.target.name], {
            validation: true
          })
        });
        this.validateForm(this.state);
      } else {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: Object.assign({}, this.state[e.target.name], {
            validation: false
          })
        });
        this.setState({ nameSubmit: "offSubmit" });
        this.setState({ validateForm: false });
      }
    }

    if (e.target.name === "password") {
      let regexCheck = RegExp(
        "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-zd$@$!%*?&]{8,}"
      );
      let password = e.target.value.trim();
      if (
        typeof password === "string" &&
        password.length >= 1 &&
        regexCheck.test(password)
      ) {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: Object.assign({}, this.state[e.target.name], {
            validation: true
          })
        });

        this.validateForm(this.state);
      } else {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: Object.assign({}, this.state[e.target.name], {
            validation: false
          })
        });
        this.setState({ nameSubmit: "offSubmit" });
        this.setState({ validateForm: false });
      }
    }
  };

  validateForm = state => {
    let validatePassword = this.state.password.validation;
    let validateEmail = this.state.email.validation;

    console.log(
      "validatePassword: " + validatePassword,
      ", validateEmail: " + validateEmail
    );
    if (validateEmail && validatePassword) {
      this.setState({ validateForm: true });
      this.setState({ nameSubmit: "onSubmit" });
      console.log("form validated, nameSubmit: ", this.state.nameSubmit);
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log("nameSubmit: ", this.state.nameSubmit);

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="email"> Email</label>
        <input
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          name="email"
          id="email"
          type="text"
          required
        />

        <label htmlFor="password"> Password </label>
        <input
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          name="password"
          id="password"
          type="text"
          required
        />

        <input
          className={style[this.state.nameSubmit]}
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I wonder what'is wrong, if anybody have an hint, would be great.

Thanks

Comment: That's because `setState` is asynchronous, so if you try to use `this.state` directly after `setState` it will not contain the updated values.

Comment: Okay I will seek for some information about that, thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but what’s the point of `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}`? Why not just give it `this.handleChange`?

Comment: @Dave Newton  great question ..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.
1. As mentioned in comments, [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) (look for "async" in the doc) is an asynchronous operation.

So `handleChange` would need to check against `e.target.name` within the callback of `setState`.

Instead of

```
handleChange = e => {

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: Object.assign({}, this.state[e.target.name], {
        value: e.target.value
      })
    });

    if (e.target.name === "email") {
      // reducerUpdateMail
    }

    if (e.target.name === "password") {
      //   reducerUpdatePassword
    }

    this.checkForm(e);
  };
```

Do

```
handleChange = e => {

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: Object.assign({}, this.state[e.target.name], {
        value: e.target.value
      }),
      () => {
            if (e.target.name === "email") {
              // "this.state.email.value" has an updated value here.
            }

            if (e.target.name === "password") {
              // "this.state.password.value" has an updated value here.
            }
      }
    });

    this.checkForm(e);
  };
```

2. For the same reason (setState being async), don't call `setState` as if it's a synchronous method.

Instead of this,

```
this.setState({ nameSubmit: "offSubmit" });
this.setState({ validateForm: false });
```

Set both states in one call.

```
this.setState({ nameSubmit: "offSubmit", validateForm: false });
```

so that the change is made at once.

And yes, if you need to access updated values for either `nameSubmit` or `validateForm` right away, check them in the callback of `setState`.